# How to read an Unsigned Char image file to Python?

Tags: image, image-processing, file-type, unsigned-char

I have an text file called with the extension '.image', at the top of the file is the following:

```
Image Type: unsigned char
Dimension: 2
Image Size: 512 512
Image Spacing: 1 1
Image Increment: 1 1
Image Axis Labels: "" "" 
Image Intensity Label: ""
193
```

I believe this to be an unsigned char file, but i'm having a hard time opening it in python (and saving it as a jpg, png etc)

Have tried the standard `PIL.Image.open()`, saving as a string and reading with `Image.fromstring('RGB', (512,512), string)`, and reading as byte-like object `Image.open(io.BytesIO(filepath))`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the file, probably using Dropbox, Google Drive or somesuch.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm afraid I cant as it contains confidential data

Comment: Mmm... not ideal. Ok, what is the size of the file in bytes please?

Comment: 262.3 kB (262,341 bytes)

Comment: Ok, if your image is 512x512 pixels, you need 262,4000 bytes plus whatever is in the header so you are missing some pixels. Try changing `h` to `500` in my code as a quick check.

Comment: 512*512 is 262144, leaving 197 bytes for the header. what are you calculating there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume there is some arbitrary, unknown length header on the file, we can read the entire file and then rather than parsing the header, just take the final 512x512 bytes from the tail of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import pathlib

# Slurp the entire contents of the file
f = pathlib.Path('image.raw').read_bytes()

# Specify height and width
h, w = 512, 512

# Take final h*w bytes from the tail of the file and treat as greyscale values, i.e. mode='L'
im = Image.frombuffer('L', (w,h), f[-(h*w):], "raw", 'L', 0, 1)

# Save to disk
im.save('result.png')
```

---

Or, if you prefer Numpy to Pathlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Specify height and width
h, w = 512, 512

# Slurp entire file into Numpy array, take final 512x512 bytes, and reshape to 512x512
na = np.fromfile('image.raw', dtype=np.uint8)[-(h*w):].reshape((h,w))

# Make Numpy array into PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save('result.png')
```

---

Or, if you don't really fancy writing any Python, just use `tail`  in Terminal to slice the last 512x512 bytes off your file and tell **ImageMagick** to make an 8-bit PNG from the grayscale byte values:

```
tail -c $((512*512)) image.raw | magick -depth 8 -size 512x512  gray:- result.png
```

Comment: Mark, very thorough!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your help, but i got the following errors:`ValueError: buffer is not large enough` from the first piece of code, and `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (512,512)` for the second. Essentially the output is empty (`b''` and `array([], dtype=uint8)`

Comment: Scratch my last comment.. One of the .image files was actually empty. The other was 262kb and your code worked perfect. I shall mark your solution as correct :)

Comment: Cool - well done. Good luck with your project!